# Microsoft Live API - The access token isn't valid

Tags: live-sdk, windows-live, windows-live-id

I'm trying to implement "login with Outlook.com" flow, which involves client and server code.
The flow is:

1. from the client redirect the user to:

[https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=< client_id >&response_type=code&redirect_uri=< the login html page >&scope=openid+offline_access+profile+https:%2f%2foutlook.office.com%2fmail.send+https:%2f%2foutlook.office.com%2fcontacts.read+onedrive.readwrite](https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=000000004C113E18&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.capsoole.com%2Fmsnlogin.html&scope=openid%20offline_access%20profile%20https:%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fmail.send%20https:%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fcontacts.read%20onedrive.readwrite)

2. I get the code back to my html page and post it to MY java server.
3. **On the server side** I use the code to obtain access and refresh token, using a POST request to:
   https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf

with the next parameters in the body: client_id, redirect_uri, client_secret, grant_type="authorization_code" and code=< the code from the previous step >.

I receive the access_token and refresh_tokem and they are supposed to valid for 1 hour.

4. Still on the server, I call the URL

https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=< the access-token I just got >

and get error 401:

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_token_invalid", 
      "message": "The access token isn't valid."
   }
}
```

Is this flow possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this working.

First of all, the correct endpoint for obtaining user information is:
**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me**

Secondly, the scope in step 1 should not be set to `openid ...` but rather **`User.Read`**.